# Visual Studio Error: DEP6250

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

everytime I try to start my app on my Lumia 1020 I get this error:

```
Error: DEP6250 : The Device runs on a not supported version of the OS
```

(I translated it from german...)

I "unlocked" my phone a few minutes ago so I think that this won't be the problem.

I also searched for an update but everything is fine...

I used the free Visual Studio express 2013 for store developers

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: are you trying to deploy a Windows Phone 8.1 project on a machine running Windows Phone 8 OS?

Comment: Yes but I knew it just after I asked this question (That I have Windows Phone 8 and not 8.1... thought it'd be up to date because my system said so)... 
But now I have another problem - I don't know how to create an empty project for windows phone 8...

Comment: After you've got the update, you'll not be able to create WinRT WP 8 apps but still you can create WP8 Silverlight apps for WP. Or else if you already have a WP8 project you could continue with it or else could upgrade it to 8.1!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are probably trying to deploy a Windows Phone 8.1 app to a device running Windows Phone 8.0. That is not possible. You need to Either create a Windows Phone 8.0 app and run it on the device or update your device to Windows Phone 8.1 in order to run WP8.1 apps. Windows Phone 8.0 apps will work on WP8.1 but the other way around will not happen.